# Inconsistent accessibility filed type system.collections.generic.list

Tags: c#, generics

When I am trying to make a `List` public, like so:

```
public List<Enemy> enemies;
```

I got the following error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'...

Comment: Class Enemy is not public...

Comment: well if your class `Enemy` is not publis then that would answer your own question..

Comment: If you're going to mention the question you asked not even a 2 hours ago, at least link to it.

Comment: The default class type is internal not private.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey Strictly speaking the default accessibility of *anything* is the smallest level that is legal in context.  For a top level type, that happens to be `internal`.  For a nested class, it's `private`.  For any members of a class it'll be `private`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because `Enemy` is not `public`

See [Compiler Error CS0052](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/997yz02a.aspx):

> The type of a field cannot be less accessible than the field itself because all public constructs must return a publicly accessible object.

Answer (score 0):

What is your class "Enemy" accessibility? It should be public if you are using a list of objects.

Comment: It should not be public because he's using a list of object, it should be public because there is a public field.